# android how to digitally sign app with trusted(!) certificate

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, digital-certificate

I've found quite interesting webpage explaining how to sign Android apps - perhaps it can be useful for someone [link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Distributing_Android_apps)

However as general rule you sign your app with keys generated by yourself.

I'm wondering if it was a much better idea to sign with certificate confirmed by well known certification authority. From one side I don't want to exagerate and to pay too much (or even I would prefer to get it for free if possible), from another I believe it looks much professional.

Concluding can you recommend any certification authority which:
- is well known,
- give basic certifcate basing on e-mail address only,
- they give their services for free, or for very small fee (ex. 5 usd)?

Answer (score 3):

I do not get the point why you should do this this way. Most of the steps are identical to these which you would take when you do everything on your own.

Additionally I will quote from another thread:

"You can not use a Verisign or other commercial code-signing certificate to sign Android APKs for distribution in Android Market. The Android Market requires that the certificate expiry date have a year greater than or equal to 2033, but no commercial certificate vendor will sell you a cert with an expiry date that far in the future (their business is forcing you to come back and pay every year: selling you a 3-decade cert kind of defeats that). See http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode for the date information.

So no, you can not use a commercial authority cert." (see top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209734/android-obtain-a-key-from-a-certification-authority-like-verisign))

Comment: Ok so for Android market probably using a not confirmed certificate is a must. But what if I want to create my own website and put my app there to give also the possibility to download directly from the website. Then app signed by certificate confirmed by well known certification authority would make to look my app a bit more credible. Am I right? How to prove to user that my app "doesn't have bad intentions"? My proposal is to sign it in the way I mentionned plus reduce the number of permissions required as much as possible (only one, two permissions required).

Comment: I do not know whether the average user would recognize that your app is signed by some special authority. And it would not provide better security so I do still not get why one should pay money for something you can do on your own. If you want to give your user a secure impression of your app you should probably name the reasons for the permissions your app asks for.

Comment: Ok, but getting to the point "Concluding can you recommend any certification authority which: - is well known, - give basic certifcate basing on e-mail address only, - they give their services for free, or for very small fee (ex. 5 usd)?" It can be useful for other purposes in the future...

Comment: All I have found is http://www.symantec.com/verisign/code-signing/android which can also sign android apps. But the problem is that this tool only provides 25 years validity. The Playstore needs more than 25 years validity period which means that you cannot distribute your signed app via the Playstore. On your website it should be ok and can also make users feel more secure due to the (at least in Germany) well known security label. But I guess that it is too expensive anyway. I am sorry but I don't know any other authority which signs apps.

Comment: 500 USD, it's definitely not worth. :( Perhaps someone else know something more reasonable?